# Equivalence between conditions for convergence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_k)$ be independant random variables such that $X_k\sim\mathcal{P}(p_k)$ (Poisson distribution with parameter $p_k$). So in particular we have $ \sum_{n=1}^NX_k \sim \mathcal{P}(\sum _{n=1}^Np_k)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_k)=p_k$. By hypothesis $np_n\to \infty$ and can be write : $p_n=b(n)/n$ where $b(n)$ is slowly varying function.

A function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is a slowly varying function if for every $\delta >0$, $n^{\delta }f(n)$ is increasing and $n^{\delta }f(n)$ is decreasing if $n$ is large enough. So in particular we have $p_n\to 0$.

I want to show equivalence between the following conditions :

> i) a.s. $\forall t \neq 0 \in \mathbb{T}, \, \sum_{k=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_k>0\}}e^{2i\pi kt}=o( \sum_{k=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_k>0\}})$ when $N\to \infty$.
>
> ii)a.s. $\forall t \neq 0 \in \mathbb{T}, \, \sum_{k=1}^NX_ke^{2i\pi kt}=o( \sum_{k=1}^NX_k)$ when $N\to \infty$.
>
> iii)a.s. $\forall t \neq 0 \in \mathbb{T}, \, \sum_{k=1}^NX_ke^{2i\pi kt}=o( \sum_{k=1}^Np_k)$ when $N\to \infty$.

The notation $\sum_{k=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_k>0\}}e^{2i\pi kt}=o( \sum_{k=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_k>0\}})$ means that $$ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_k>0\}}e^{2i\pi kt}}{\sum_{k=1}^N\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_k>0\}}}\to 0$$ when $N\to \infty$.

The torus will be denoted by $\mathbb{T}=[0,1)=\mathbb{R}\setminus  \mathbb{Z}$.

First observe that $\sum _k p_k=\infty $. But we can obtain a more precise estimation : $\sum _k^N p_k=a_N\log (N)$ where $a_N\to \infty$ when $N\to \infty$.
So by using Chernoff bound we can show (cf Mickael's answer) that $ii)\implies iii)$ since $ \sum _k X_k\leq M \sum _k p_k$ with probability one. The same argument can be used to show that with probability one $ \sum _k p_k\leq m \sum _k X_k$. So $ii)\Leftrightarrow iii)$.

It remains to show the equivalence between $i)$ and $ii)$ and $iii)\implies ii)$. I suggest the following argument.

Let $Y_k=X_k-\mathbf{1}_{\{ X_k>0\}}$, $\mathbb{P}(Y_k>0)=e^{-p_k}\sum _{n\geq 2}\frac{p_k^n}{n!}$. So $\sum _k\mathbb{P}(Y_k>0)<\sum _n \sum _k \frac{p_k^2}{n!}<+\infty $ (we can assume that $0<p_k<1$ and by hypothesis $\sum p_k^2=\sum b(k)^2/k^2<+\infty$). By Borel-Cantelli lemma $Y_k=0$ a.s. for sufficiently large $k$. Since $\sum _k X_k \to \infty$ the result follows.

Comment: Indeed, $t\in (0,1)$. I didn't see a mistake on indices of summation.

Comment: As @Teepeemm mentions, you should change your summation index from $n$ to $k$.  Also define: (i) $\mathbb{T}$, (ii) Notation "$\forall t \neq 0 \in \mathbb{T}$," (iii) What is meant by a complex-valued function being $o(\cdot)$, (iv) define a "slowly varying function."

Comment: Also, how can you "very easily show the sum $\sum_{k=1}^N X_k$ tends to infinity" if you do not specify the $b(n)$ function?  For example, if $b(n)=1/n$ then $p(n) = 1/n^2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k$ is finite with probability 1.

Comment: Intuitively, if $b(n)=1$ for all $n$, I would not expect the statements to be true, even if they are equivalent.

Comment: It is also not clear why we can assume $0 < p_k < 1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b(k)^2/k^2 < \infty$.  The latter is not true, for example, if $b(k)=k$.  Overall, this problem is not stated clearly. I do agree with your conclusions that if $0 < p_k < 1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b(k)^2/k^2 < \infty$, then with prob 1 we have  $X_k = 1_{\{X_k>0\}}$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: @Michael You seem to be making more headway in this than I, but I'll point you to some information for [slowly varying function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function).  Think: "$b(k)$ is like  $\log(k)$".

Comment: In that case, if you assume there is a $c>0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n \geq c\log(K)$, you get my new Claim 3 below.

Comment: I think some misunderstanding are due to my lack of English ability. I didn't state clearly hypothesis.

The convergence of an infinite serie of random variables is a tail event. Since $E(\sum _k X_k)=\sum _k p_k =\infty $ there is a set with strictly positive probability for wich the serie diverge. By $0-1$ law the serie diverge almost surely. (Is this a correct reasoning ?!)

$b(n)$ is slowly variation function iff for every $\delta >0$, $n^\delta b(n)$ is an increasing function and  $n^{-\delta }b(n)$ is non-increasing for $n$ big enough. That implies wikipedia caracterization.

Comment: So with this definition we have $p_n=\lambda _n= b(n)/n\to 0$. We can also show that $\sum _{n=1}^K\lambda _n=a_Kln (K)$ with $a_K\to \infty$.

Comment: I didn't realized how my post was poorly written. I've fixed some mistakes thanks to your contribution.

Comment: If $b(n)=1$ for all $n$ then that satisfies your "slowly varying" condition and also gives $\sum_{n=1}^K \lambda_n  = \sum_{n=1}^K 1/n \approx \log(K)$. There is no $a_K\rightarrow\infty$.  Of course, if you have a different $b(n)$ such that there is an $a_K\rightarrow\infty$ then that satisfies my condition $\sum_{n=1}^K \lambda_n \geq c \log(K)$ for $c=1$.

Comment: The last time I edited my initial message I've added the hypothesis $b(n)=np_n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some related results: Define $\lambda_n = p_n = E[X_n]$.

Claim 1: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n < \infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n < \infty$ with prob. 1.

Proof: Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n < \infty$.  Then: 
\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Pr[X_n>0] &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [1-e^{-\lambda_n}] \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n < \infty
\end{align} 
and hence (with prob 1) $X_n=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$. So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n < \infty$ with prob 1. $\Box$

Claim 2: For all $z>0$ and all positive integers $K$ we have:
$$Pr\left[\frac{\sum_{n=1}^K X_n}{\sum_{n=1}^{K} \lambda_n} \geq z\right] \leq e^{-(z+1-e)\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n}$$

Proof: By the Chernov bound we have:
\begin{align} 
Pr\left[\sum_{n=1}^K X_n \geq z\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n\right] &\leq E[e^{\sum_{n=1}^KX_n}]e^{-z\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n}\\
&=\left(\prod_{n=1}^KE[e^{X_n}]\right)e^{-z\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n}\\
&= \left(\prod_{n=1}^K e^{\lambda_n(e-1)} \right) e^{-z\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n}\\
&= e^{-(z+1-e)\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n} 
\end{align} 
$\Box$

For example, using $z=2$ in Claim 2 gives for all positive integers $K$:

$$ Pr\left[ \frac{\sum_{n=1}^KX_n}{\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n} \geq 2 \right] \leq  e^{-(3-e)\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n} $$

and if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n=\infty$ then the probability on the left-hand-side goes to $0$ as $K\rightarrow\infty$.

Claim 3:  If there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^K \lambda_n \geq c\log(K)$ for all positive integers $K$, then with prob 1 we know $\sum_{n=1}^K X_n \leq \left(e-1+\frac{2}{c}\right)\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n$ for all sufficiently large $K$.  Thus, with prob 1 we have $\sum_{n=1}^KX_n \leq \Theta(\sum_{n=1}^K \lambda_n)$.

Proof: Define $z = e-1 + 2/c$. By Claim 2 we have: 
\begin{align} 
Pr\left[\sum_{n=1}^KX_n \geq z\sum_{n=1}^K \lambda_n\right] 
&\leq  e^{-(z+1-e)\sum_{n=1}^{K}\lambda_n}\\
&\leq e^{-(z+1-e)c\log(K)}\\
&= e^{-2\log(K)} \\
&= 1/K^2
\end{align} 
Since $1/K^2$ is summable, it follows (with prob 1) that  $\sum_{n=1}^KX_n \leq z\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n$ for all sufficiently large $K$. $\Box$

In the same way, if there is a constant $d>0$ such that $\sum_{K=1}^{\infty} e^{-d\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n} < \infty$, then with prob 1 we have $\sum_{n=1}^KX_n \leq \Theta(\sum_{n=1}^K\lambda_n)$.  This follows immediately from Claim 2 by defining $z$ such that $z+1-e=d$.